# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: filepath[0] is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, try-catch, typeerror

I'm trying to catch this error using a try catch block, but it keeps crashing my application. Is it not possible to catch TypeErrors?
This is the code for the try catch block:

```
    try{
        for (const file of filepath[0]){
            const filename = file.name
            
            await axios.post('/api/filesRoute/fs', { filename : filename })
                .then((json) => {
                    console.log('Success uploading ', filename)
                    raws.push(json.data.id)
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    setError(e)
                    setFilepath([])
                })
        }
    }
    catch(TypeError){
        setError(TypeError)
    }
```

This error happens when filepath[0] is not iterable, so when users don't upload files.

Comment: "Is it not possible to catch TypeErrors?" try-catch blocks catch all errors, you can't specify which errors to catch and you can't know which errors are thrown. Unsure why you've named the error parameter to `TypeError` which is unusual because it's a built in object. If you're expecting your code to throw type errors you should guard against errors instead of catching them. `if (filepath[0]){...}`

Comment: Why not just check for it before you start? `if (filePath && filepath[0]) {/*code*/}`. Also it will be more performant if you start all the calls and then await them once with promise.all

Comment: @AmyBlankenship You're right, that would probably work better. Can you elaborate on promise.all? How should I use it in this context? Thank you!

Comment: Something like...`const promises = files.map((file) => { axios.post(*your code here*});`
`const raws = Promise.all(promises).then((arrOfResults) => arrOfResults.map((res) => res.json()).catch((err) => {setError(err); setFilePath([])});`